# Is it idiomatic to say someone is "obstinate about" something they don't want changed?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, collocations

> John is very obstinate about his choice of words.

Above is a sentence I wrote about a person I know. He's a self-professed novelist who is very stubborn about his choice of words. When he wraps up a novel, he would share it with his friends for feedback. Yet, he tends to get very worked up if anyone suggests tweaking his phrasing.

Is "*obstinate about*" a natural combination? Does it make sense in that sentence?

Comment: I think ***obstinate*** (and to a lesser extent, ***stubborn***) are *slightly* unusual words for the exact context. To me, both of them tend to imply refusing to change one's behaviour *even when it's causing inconvenience to others.* I'd prefer ***intransigent***, which simply means *doesn't change his mind easily, sticks to his guns*. But that's just my personal preference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the suggestion! Just to follow up: if I use intransigent, what should be the preposition?

Comment: **Scrupulous** also corresponds to this conscientious carefulness.

Comment: By far the most common usage refers to someone being *intransigent **in** their **position***. But you could use ***about, concerning, regarding,...*** It's no big deal. I'm more intrigued by the fact that apparently other people seem to ***want*** John to use different words. Why should he? Is it taken for granted the people trying to get him to change know better than him? I don't really understand why John should feel obliged to change his words in the first place, or why he's being "awkward" if he refuses to do so.

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+obstinate+*_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) gives a clue about which prepositions collocate with "obstinate". Best to look up each one and make sure the preposition is being used to modify the object of the obstinance.

Comment: To be obstinate about something is fine. The preposition will always be about/ About ,means about a subject. about is the most common way to say it. In your description about your friend, obstinate sounds OKAY,

Comment: @FumbleFingers - personally, I think 'intransigent' is what my mother would have called a 'seven-and-sixpenny' word. That is, too learned nd 'educated' for most everyday purposes. I would rather say that my dog is obstinate about giving up a bone.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, as I understand it, we're talking about would-be "writers" and "literary critics" here, so it should be okay to use words that might be outside your dog's working vocabulary as in *Don't be so **intransigent,** Rover! Just let Kitty share your bone!* :)